# How to Connect dense layer to Conv2D in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to map an input of 61 intensity values to an image of size 64×64. The code I use is given below.

**Network Input=61×1** (intensity values)

**OUTPUT=64×64**(image)

```
input_img = Input(shape=(61,))

x = Dense(250, activation='relu')(input_img)
x = Dense(500, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)

x=Conv2D(16,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(x)


x=Conv2D(1,(3,3),padding='same',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(x)
```

The dimensions are giving me problems.
How can I shape the dimensions in the code so that I can get correct mapping as 64×64 size at output.

The code error is ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_14: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The probable problem is `input_img` shape.

It should actually contain 3 dimensions. And internally keras will add the batch dimension making it 4.

Since you used `input_img` with 1 dimensions (vector), keras is adding the 2nd.

You should correct the shape of your `input_img`

Comment: To pass my data now I have to convert from (Batch size, 61) to (Batch size, 61,1,1).?

Comment: The problem is that if I check the shape of Conv tensor I get (None,61,1,16) ...whereas I need (64,64,1) as the pipit is an image of size 64x64. What am I missing here???

Comment: you should include batch_size also.

Comment: How can I add batch size. I think it's given on the run by Kerala from training data. Can you give me an example. Thanks